# else statement python programming

Tags: python

How can I link the second `info()` call to a text file ?

```
print("Hi,welcome to the multiple choice quiz")

def info ():
    print("Firstly we would like to collect some personal details:-?")
    name = input("Please enter your first name?")
    surname =input ("please enter your surname?")
    email_address = input ("please enter your email addres @.co.uk")
    username = input (" Chose a username?")
    password = input ("Enter a Password?")
    validation()


def validation():
    correct = 0
    while correct == 0:
        correct=input(" is the following data is correct ?")
        if correct in ["Y,y"]:
            print("Well done you have registered for the quiz")
        elif correct in ["N,n"]:
            info()
        else:
            info()
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to drop your while loop.

info() calls your validation. "if" the data is correct, you finish, "else" you just call info() again.

That is pretty much what you did already. maybe you wanted it to look more like this:

```
print("Hi, welcome to the multiple choice quiz")

def info ():
    print("Firstly we would like to collect some personal details:-?")
    name = input("Please enter your first name?")
    surname = input("please enter your surname?")
    email_address = input("please enter your email address @.co.uk")
    username = input(" Chose a username?")
    password = input("Enter a Password?")
    validation()


def validation():
       correct = 0
       correct = input(" is the data is correct ?")
       if correct in ["Y,y"]:
             print("Well done you have registered for the quiz")
       elif correct in ["Y,y"]:
           info()
       else:
           print "please type y or n"
           validation()

info()
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
if correct in ["Y,y"]:
    print("Well done you have registered for the quiz")
elif correct in ["N,n"]:
    info()
else:
    info()
```

Firstly, `correct in ["Y,y"]` will not do what you expect. `["Y,y"]` is a list containing one element: `"Y,y"`. That means `correct in ["Y,y"]` if and only if `correct == "Y,y"`, and the user is not likely to enter that! You probably want a list with two elements: `["Y", "y"]`. `in` can also test containment within strings, so you could use `"Yy"`. You don't want a comma in there because then if the user enters just a comma that will pass the test as well, which is silly.

Putting that issue aside, if the user enters y or Y, it prints well done. If they enter n or N, `info()` is called. If they enter something else, `info()` is still called. That last part is surely not what you want: entering "N" and entering "A" should have different results! You want the user to be told that it's not valid. That part is easy, print a message. Then you want them to be asked again. Since they'll be asked for every iteration of your while loop, you just have to ensure that the loop continues. The loop will run as long as the condition `correct == 0` is true, so just set `correct` to 0 and that will happen. So something like this:

```
else:
    print("That's not valid")
    correct = 0
```

OK, now to your question. You want to save those personal details to a file. You can't do that properly with the way your program is organised. The variables in `info` are local, so `validation` can't access them to save them. `info` has to do the saving (perhaps indirectly by passing the data along to another function). What we could do is have `validation` report the result of asking the user and let `info` decide what to do based on that:

```
def info ():
    # collect data
    if validation():
        # save data

def validation():
    correct = 0
    while correct == 0:
        correct=input(" is the following data is correct ?")
        if correct in ["Y", "y"]:
            print("Well done you have registered for the quiz")
            return True
        elif correct in ["N", "n"]:
            return False
        else:
            print("That's not valid")
            correct = 0
```

`return` will exit the `validation` function (thus ending the loop) and give the value returned to `info` to decide if the data should be saved.

Since the return statements end the loop, the only way the loop can continue is the `else` is reached, in which case explicitly making it continue with `correct = 0` is silly. We can just make the loop go on forever until the function returns:

```
def validation():
    while True:
        correct=input(" is the following data is correct ?")
        if correct in ["Y", "y"]:
            print("Well done you have registered for the quiz")
            return True
        elif correct in ["N", "n"]:
            info()
            return False
        else:
            print("That's not valid")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i got it to wrik eventually but still thanks for you inlut and help much appreciated